# Is there a way to set a custom certificate in puppeteer?

Tags: python, web-scraping, ssl-certificate, puppeteer, chromium

The site requires special certificates, I need to register them for the browser, I can't use standard requests, because I need JS

```
async def main():
    browser = await launch(options={'ignoreHTTPSErrors': True})
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto("my_url")
    await page.screenshot({'path': 'example.png'})
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main2())
```